# How can I downloading a pdf file to someplace other than downloads

Tags: macos, safari

When downloading a pdf file in Safari 11.0.2, can I save it in a particular file folder without first saving it in Downloads?

Answer (score 3):

Right click the link & 'Download Linked File as...'

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, go to Safari preferences and select General. In this window, you can define a download folder to use. Just change it from the default Download folder in your user account to another location you want. Close the preferences and start downloading.